# JS Passing Additional Parameters for Bind Callback

Tags: javascript, events, bind

I have a callback function and would like to pass in parameters. I read you can use Apply but I found it to be overly complex and confusing. Here is my binding function:

```
function onPlotZoom (event, plot, args ) {
   $.each( plot.getAxes(), function( event, axisName, axis) {
      options[axisName].min = axis.min;
      options[axisName].max = axis.max;
      options[axisName].scale = axis.scale;
   }
}


$( "#plot" ).bind( "plotzoom", onPlotZoom );
```

My script also has variables which listen on the document whether shift and ctrl pressed and stored like so:

```
var isShiftPressed = false;
var isCtrlPressed = false;
```

How can I pass these 2 variables into the callback onPlotZoom? I have tried the following:

```
$( "#plot" ).bind( "plotzoom", onPlotZoom( isShiftPressed, isCtrlPressed ) );

function onPlotZoom (event, plot, isShiftPressed, isCtrlPressed ) {
   $.each( plot.getAxes(), function( event, axisName, axis) {
      if(isShiftPressed) {
          //do stuff
      }
      if(isCtrlPressed) {
          // do stuff
      }
      options[axisName].min = axis.min;
      options[axisName].max = axis.max;
      options[axisName].scale = axis.scale;
   }
}
```

another method I tried was using args and obtaining the property. But this resulted in a cannot find property 0 error:

```
$( "#plot" ).bind( "plotzoom", onPlotZoom( isShiftPressed, isCtrlPressed ) );

function onPlotZoom (event, plot, args) {
     var isShiftPressed = args[0];
     var isCtrlPressed  = args[1];
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Don't pass them, don't declare them as parameters, just use them through closure!

Comment: "*I read you can use Apply*" - not really, no. Where did you read that?

Comment: I read it somewhere on here but I may have misread. I tried using them without passing as param but when debugging within the function if statements it states isShiftPressed and isCtrlPressed is invalid.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do so? Im not too familiar with JS.

Comment: Start learning about closures :-) You say your script "*has variables*", are they in scope?

Comment: Sorry mean to say `undefined` not `invalid` in my previous comment. the variables are declared as var at the top of the script, I assume global space so i think it would be in scope of the function.

Comment: Yes they should then. Are you sure you did not re-declare them somewhere in between (e.g. as function parameters)?